# Selling middleware

Tags: middleware, sales

I am close to completion of a useful suite of tools for 2D game development (with mobile platforms in mind), for working with sprites and animations.

Can anyone advise the best way to sell and promote my product (without investing capital). I am aware that there are lots of websites that can market and sell software to end consumers, but I need to target game developers specifically as middleware is completely meaningless to your average joe.

So, aside from using PayPal on my website, are there any marketplaces for game middleware? How can I promote the application outside my website without spamming developer forums?

Comment: There are free libraries for this exact purpose already, covering not only sprites and animations, but a lot of other things. I predict you'll have a really hard time no matter what. Also, I don't think this belongs here.

Comment: Google adwords? Hit just the folks who are actively looking for something like you're selling..

Comment: @tdammers I'm not talking just libraries, I have made a suite of GUI interfaces for manipulating graphics and animations that can be used by artists working on game dev as well as coders. It's actually extremely useful and have spoken to multiple developers who have expressed a desire to trial my software at their company. But thanks for the words of encouragement. And why doesn't this belong here?

Comment: This is likely more appropriate on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Sorry if this question bothered people. I did search for 'Selling' on here first and saw plenty of people asking the same kind of question about end user software and getting helpful and polite responses without being downvoted so I assumed it was a legitimate question. I'll try gamedev.stackexchange.com then!

Comment: This 'question' is starting to read like an advert... The reason tdammers said that the question doesn't belong here is that it's not a programming problem - it's a IT sales / marketing problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your market segment looks small, but you can always try yourself, of course.

First of all, you need to setup your site (this is obvious, right) and make it visible on search engines (read about search engine optimization, SEO).

Now you need to setup proper order processing procedure on your site. Having paypal only is not the best idea for a variety of reasons. We use Avangate and Share-it services for handling orders. They process both credit cards, wire transfers, checks and paypal.

Next, communities (forums, newsgroups) were and remain to be the place to find customers. Spamming as making unsolicited posts is, of course, not a good idea, but if someone asks for a tool, and you know that your tool is the right one in this case, then why not reply and tell about your tool? Yes, there exists a category of inadequate people, who treat each such message as spam, but you have to live with this (keeping in mind, that the world is full of alternatively minded people).

If you have absolutely no budget, then unfortunately this is all you can do at the moment. Once you earn something, start using Google Adwords to promote your product. It does work. Next, highly-targeted advertising on different sites works as well.

I wouldn't expect high sales from product of your kind, and it's especially important to choose right pricing and licensing model.

And remember that when you sell a license, you sell not just code, but also support and promises for future. While end-user software is sold as is, developer tools and components usually require certain level of support. If you are not ready to provide it after the license is sold, - don't start charging money (better put it as freeware and earn by something else like custom services).